# Problema a la hora de iniciar sesión en con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, html5, laravel-6

Estoy teniendo un ligero problema en un proyecto que estoy realizando.

A la hora de iniciar sesión con alguna de las cuentas disponibles, retorno la vista perfil, donde muestro la barra de navegación, donde, cuando un usuario es logeado, se debe mostrar su nombre de usuario junto a un menú desplegable que posee la opción de cerrar sesión, hasta ahí todo bien.

El caso, es que si quiero dirigirme a la página de inicio o a cualquier otra, el nombre de usuario desaparece y vuelven a mostrarse las opciones de inicio de sesión y de registro.

[image: Vista del perfil]

[image: Vista de la pagína de inicio tras haber iniciado sesión]

Aquí dejo el código encargado del inicio de sesión:

```
public function checkLogin()
{

    request()->validate([
        "email" => "required|email",
        "password" => "required"
    ]);

    $user_data = [
        "email" => request("email"),
        "password" => request("password")
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($user_data)) {

        return view("users.profile");

    } else {

        return back()->with("error", "Ha ocurrido un error al iniciar sesión");

    }

}
```

Aquí las rutas:

```
//Route::views

Route::view("/inicio", "homepage")->name("homepage");
Route::view("/libros", "books.listBooks")->name("books.list");
Route::view("/login", "users.login")->name("users.showLogin");
Route::view("/registro", "users.registry")->name("users.registry");
Route::view("/perfil", "users.profile")->name("users.profile");

//Route::post

Route::post("/signIn", "UsersController@register")->name("users.register");
Route::post("/usersLogin", "UsersController@checkLogin")->name("users.login");


//Route::get
Route::get("/logout", "UsersController@logout")->name("logout");
```

Y aquí el código HTML de la barra de navegación, donde compruebo cuando deben mostrarse las opciones de registro y login y cuando debe mostarse el nombre de usuario junto a las opciones de cerrar sesión y dirigirse al perfil.

```html
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ route("homepage") }}" class="nav-link">Inicio</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ route("books.list") }}" class="nav-link">Libros</a>
            </li>

            @auth()

                <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-5">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        {{auth()->user()->username}}
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route("users.profile") }}">Perfil</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route("logout") }}">Cerrar sesión</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            @endauth

        </ul>


        @guest()
            <ul class="navbar-nav">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ route("users.showLogin") }}" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ route("users.registry") }}" class="nav-link" style="margin-left: 5px">Registro</a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        @endguest

    </div>
```

También dejo el formulario de inicio de sesión, por si hiciera falta:

```
                    <form action="{{ route("users.login") }}" method="post">

                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="{{ 

    old("email") }}">


</div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    @if($message = Session::get("error"))

                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                            <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
                        </div>

                    @endif

                    @if(count($errors) > 0)

                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>
                                        {{ $error }}
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    @endif

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Iniciar sesión</button>

   </form>
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda / consejo

Muchas gracias

Comment: Prueba poniendo las rutas que mencionas como "cualquier otra" dentro del middleware auth. Por ejemplo: `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { Route::view("/libros", "books.listBooks")->name("books.list"); });`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ he hecho lo que has dicho, "encerrar" las rutas necesarias dentro del group donde menciono las route::views que me interesan, quedando de la siguiente manera:


Route::group(["middleware" => "auth"], function () {
    Route::view("/inicio", "homepage")->name("homepage");
    Route::view("/libros", "books.listBooks")->name("books.list");
    Route::view("/perfil", "users.profile")->name("users.profile");
});

El caso es que al hacer eso, las vistas requieren la ruta "login", la cual es la predeterminada por el middleware auth, y que yo no uso

Comment: La ruta del login la puedes especificar en el método `redirectTo` del middleware [app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php), cambiasela por el nombre de tu ruta login `return route('users.showLogin');`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ supongo que te refieres a la ruta profile, para que una vez se logee redireccione al perfil, o me equivoc?

Comment: No no, si el usuario no inició sesión, el middleware lo redirecciona a la ruta del login. La del perfil es para cuando el usuario, a través del formulario de login, inicia sesión, ahí sí lo redireccionas al perfil.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ tienes razón, lo he cambiado como me dijiste, y a la hora de dirigirme a cualquier vista me aparece lo siguiente:

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. 

Y el metodo que redirige lo puse de la siguiente manera:

  protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('users.login');
        }
    }

Comment: la ruta es `route('users.showLogin')` no ` route('users.login')`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Tienes razón, fallo mío, pero ahora, aunque me haya logeado, me redirige a la página de login:

Route::group(["middleware" => "auth"], function () {
    Route::view("/perfil", "users.profile")->name("users.profile");
});

Modifiqué el route::group, ya que había metido ahí el inicio y el apartado de libros

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el controlador, donde compruebas que el usuario puede hacer login y lo reenvias a la vista del perfil. Debes crear una instancia de usuario para que Laravel pueda acceder al usuario a posteriori:

```
public function checkLogin()
{

    request()->validate([
        "email" => "required|email",
        "password" => "required"
    ]);

    $user_data = [
        "email" => request("email"),
        "password" => request("password")
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($user_data)) {
        Auth::login(App\User::where('email',$user_data['email'])->first()); //Haz el login
        return view("users.profile");

    } else {

        return back()->with("error", "Ha ocurrido un error al iniciar sesión");

    }

}
```

Si el codigo no te funciona, prueba con `User` en vez de `App\User` ya que depende de las importaciones que realices al inicio de la clase.

Btw, porque no utilizas directamente el sistema de Login que ofrece Laravel? si quieres añadir algo más, es mejor extender su sistema que crear uno nuevo

Comment: Con el método de `attempt` es suficiente, si las credenciales coinciden, se iniciará una nueva sesión autenticada para el usuario y no es necesario instanciarlo, basta con redireccionarlo. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: ¿Entonces tal vez sea necesario un redirect? Para almacenar la sesión o alguna cosa que esté faltando, tal vez

Comment: Generalmente se usa un redirect, o un `redirect()->intended()` para que después del login, redireccione a la url que el usuario estaba intentando acceder, pero puedes tranquilamente devolver una vista. A lo que iba, es que `attempt` ya inicia la sesión para el usuario, y no necesitas hacer un login manual. Por lo que veo en la pregunta, el problema puede estar en que las rutas no están dentro del middleware `auth`, entonces toma al usuario como "guest" en el navbar. Pero haría falta más información para estar seguro, por eso le dejé un comentario al OP para que pruebe si es eso.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ he intentado usar un redirect al perfil, pero, a parte del error de que no encuentra la ruta login, me aparece el error "trying to get of non-object email". Dicha instrucción se encuentra en la vista del perfil, donde compruebo si el usuario ha sido logeado mediante "Auth::user()->email"

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezDíaz no veo donde usas `Auth::user()->email`, sólo veo `{{auth()->user()->username}}` y está dentro de la directiva `@auth`, por lo que no dería darte problemas

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ quizá no se ve bien en todo el código de arriba, aquí está:

if(Auth::user()->email)

    <div class="alert alert-danger success-block">
        <strong>
            Bienvenido {{ Auth::user()->username }}
        </strong>

        <br>
        <form action="{{ route("logout") }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cerrar sesión</button>
        </form>

    </div>

endif

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezDíaz No se vé porque no está ese codigo en la pregunta, deberías agregarlo ahí en vez de en los comentarios. De todas maneras lo puedes resolver poniendo la ruta que devuelve esa vista dentro del middleware `auth`, ya que el perfil sólo debería poder verlo el usuario autenticado

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Añadí dicha ruta al grupo que gestiona el middleware